# How to use json in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to use FullCalendar.js in my application, the problem is that I'm going to add events to the calendar from db, and I don't know how to pass the json to it, example:

The way that works:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          events: [
                {
                  title: 'Event 1',
                  start: '2021-08-01'
                },
                {
                  title: 'Event 2',
                  start: '2021-08-07',
                  end: '2021-08-10'
                },
              ],
          selectable: true,
          editable: true,
        });
```

What I need to do is to manipulate the json to add my events to the calendar, I tried to do in this way, but it did not work:

```
       var obj = [{title: 'Event 1',start: '2021-08-01'},{title: 'Event 2',start: '2021-08-07',},];
       var json = JSON.stringify(obj);

        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          events: json,
          selectable: true,
          editable: true,
        });
```

Can someone help me with that ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why are you stringifying it into a JSON string?

Comment: What you are doing makes no sense. I guess you are getting your events from database as a JSON string. So go other way around an JSON.parse the return from the database before adding it to the calendar

Comment: According to [the docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) to use JSON you must pass a URL which returns JSON, rather than give it a JSON string.

Comment: Thanks guys, it helped me a lot.